# Pandas: replicating SASs proc means by attribute out=agg

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function foo that operates on a dataframe; specifically two columns of the dataframe.
So something like,

```
def foo(group):
  A = group['A']
  B = group['B']
  r1 = somethingfancy(A,B) #this is now a float
  r2 = somethinggreat(A,B) #this is another float
  return {'fancy':r1,'great':r2}
```

The issue is that I would like to use this function in the following context:

```
grouped = otherDF[['someAttribute','A','B']].groupby(['someAttribute'])
agg = grouped.apply(foo)
```

The issue is that agg is now a series of DICT.  I would like to cast it as a dataframe that would essentially look like:

```
someAttribute, fancy, great
...          , ...  , ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of returning a `dict`, return a `Series`:

```
def foo(group):
    A = group['A']
    B = group['B']
    r1 = randn()
    r2 = randn()
    return Series({'fancy': r1, 'great': r2})

df = DataFrame(randn(10, 1), columns=['a'])
df['B'] = np.random.choice(['hot', 'cold'], size=10)
df['A'] = np.random.choice(['sweet', 'sour'], size=10)
df['someAttribute'] = np.random.choice(['pretty', 'ugly'], size=10)
print df.groupby('someAttribute').apply(foo)
```

gives

```
                   fancy      great
someAttribute                      
pretty             -2.35       0.01
ugly                1.09      -1.09
```

If you want `someAttribute` to be a column in the result, call `reset_index` on the result:

```
df.groupby('someAttribute').apply(foo).reset_index()
```

to get:

```
  someAttribute      fancy      great
0        pretty       0.46      -1.08
1          ugly       0.76       0.29
```